# Android Whatsapp/Chat Examples

Tags: android, chat, whatsapp, instant-messaging

Does anybody have an **example** or a **tutorial** for a Android application like **WhatsApp**? I want to understand how WhatsApp works and how it is programmed.

I want to see an example that uses a message-chat-system with `"online"-status` and `"read the message"`-information.

I used Google but I found nothing. Maybe someone has a tip.

Thanks.

Comment: most of the chatting softwares use [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) well I can't say what Whatsapp is using but for a starter that should help you app running.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/

Comment: WhatsApp used a modified XMPP service, as far as i know

Comment: Following are links for good articles on XMPP based protocol based instant chat. - http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/
- http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/ Also there is a [jchat4android](http://code.google.com/p/jchat4android/) which is Chat Application for ANDROID SDK using Jade Agent Framework. It provide location also.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on [creating a chat application for Android](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/) using GCM and GAE. It's a simple example of a chat application in general.

Comment: [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) is an open source Whatsapp alternative.

Comment: Whatsapp is real-time messaging application which makes use of ejabbered (XMPP) server. It's facilitates instant message transfer between two or many users at any given second. ERLANG is the programming language used for quickly adapting to instant updates and hot fixes. For storing multimedia files, the app uses an exclusive web server YAWS. A detailed explanation about whatsapp, click here http://blog.contus.com/how-whatsapp-works-technically-and-how-to-build-an-app-similar-to-it/

Comment: here is an open source sdk with chat, group chat, typing status, read status and other whatsapp features https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

Comment: This tutorial using Twilio IP Messaging for Android would be a good way to test and learn some basic functionality: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ip-chat/android/java

Comment: I created an unofficial client myself, it's still working.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are looking to create an instant messenger for Android, **[this code](https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)** should get you started somewhere.

Excerpt from the **[source](https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/)** :

> This is a simple IM application runs on Android, application makes
>   http request to a server, implemented in php and mysql, to
>   authenticate, to register and to get the other friends' status and
>   data, then it communicates with other applications in other devices by
>   socket interface.

**EDIT :** *Just found this! Maybe it's not related to WhatsApp. But you can use the source to understand how chat applications are programmed.*

There is a website called **[Scringo](http://www.scringo.com/)**. These awesome people provide their own SDK which you can integrate in your existing application to exploit cool features like radaring, chatting, feedback, etc. So if you are looking to integrate chat in application, you could just use their SDK. And did I say the best part? It's free!

***UPDATE : *** Scringo services will be closed down on 15 February, 2015.

Comment: Scringo looks like great. The Problem here is, when i will start the scringo example on android, i become  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scringo.scringosample/com.scringo.scringosample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class com.scringo.ScringoLeftActivationButton

Comment: The thing is I would need to see your code to figure out what's going wrong. How about making a new post specific to the error that you are getting and then attaching your code along with it ? That way you will get more help, even from others. :)

Comment: @Swayam the sample instant messanger doesn't seems to be stable, when you send another user a request, it doesn't update the screen at all.

Comment: Is it so? I would need to check again, because as far as I can remember, things were good the last time I tried.

Comment: @Swayam yes it works, just to make sure this is pure p2p right? as each android has its own server/client and they keep the number of nodes connected on each app..

Comment: @Swayam Thanks for sharing information about scringo +10 for that

Comment: @Aamir : You are welcome! :) Glad it was of help!

Comment: Scringo is indeed free and good to start with. Unfortunately they don't scale very good for large crowd. A lot of lag.. Too bad. They do a great job.

Comment: @DroidBender : Thanks for your insights. So, if you have any other better alternative, please do share. :)

Comment: @Swayam - Do we have library in Android like https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController in iOS for Messages UI.

Comment: Well, the most straightforward way would be to use 9 patch images as the background and most of the things would be done in itself. But if you are really looking for libraries, you can have a look at  http://warting.github.io/AndroidChatBubbles/

Comment: Scringo have shut down their operations  : Look for similar resources PubNub , XMPP etc

Comment: ***cries cries***

Answer (score 18):

Check out yowsup
https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup

> Yowsup is a python library that allows you to do all the previous in
>   your own app. Yowsup allows you to login and use the Whatsapp service
>   and provides you with all capabilities of an official Whatsapp client,
>   allowing you to create a full-fledged custom Whatsapp client.
>
> A solid example of Yowsup's usage is Wazapp. Wazapp is full featured
>   Whatsapp client that is being used by hundreds of thousands of people
>   around the world. Yowsup is born out of the Wazapp project. Before
>   becoming a separate project, it was only the engine powering Wazapp.
>   Now that it matured enough, it was separated into a separate project,
>   allowing anyone to build their own Whatsapp client on top of it.
>   Having such a popular client as Wazapp, built on Yowsup, helped bring
>   the project into a much advanced, stable and mature level, and ensures
>   its continuous development and maintaince.
>
> Yowsup also comes with a cross platform command-line frontend called
>   yowsup-cli. yowsup-cli allows you to jump into connecting and using
>   Whatsapp service directly from command line.

Comment: GitHub has removed this. Can you provide other location or source of this? I would be very much grateful. I googled it too much, but found nothing

Comment: @blganesh links tend to die even they are from github ;)

Comment: Sorry folks. I'm not the owner of this. I will anyways try to look for an alternate solution.

Comment: @blganesh101  - Do we have library in Android like https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController in iOS for Messages UI.

Comment: u mean this http://talkwithstranger.com/talk-to-strangers

Comment: hi do you guys have any sample for android in which they use yowsup ?