# How to send sms via wifi like viber

Tags: android, sms, wif

I am developing application like viber which is i have to send sms via wifi.There is no interruption of GSM.I have tried and finished sending sms via SIM and now need to integrate sending sms via wifi. Can u guide me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement a kind of a chat and not how to send a SMS via WiFi.

There is a good example at the Android Developers page: 
https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/

Also check this link : [Android Whatsapp/Chat Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954712/android-whatsapp-chat-examples)

gl,
Refael

Comment: Thank u for your kind reply..I know my question is not clear but u understand then reply in a right way.

Comment: as i see - we both don't have enough rep' to vote :), so you're thank is appreciated as the vote ;)