# Looking for sources that will help me create my own chat/messaging app

Tags: java, android, messaging

Hey Im a new android programmer and for an app that I'm working on I would like it to be a simple chat / messaging app. I look online for tutorials but didn't see any. If you guys know anywhere I can go for reference or templates that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: search for XMPP chat server, http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Whatsapp/Chat Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954712/android-whatsapp-chat-examples)

Answer (score 1):

may be this code can help you.. i am giving u code which works as google talk this    code will work only on gmail id's....and one more important thing u have to **download smack.jar** and import this jar file in your libs folder.....

```
public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
public static final String USERNAME = "your gmail id";
public static final String PASSWORD = "your gmail id password";
```

In the username you have to enter your gmail id...and in the place of password you have to enter your gmail id password..... follow code and if you want any clearification please notify me....

> **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.androidwithoutxmppdialog;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

 public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
 public static final int PORT = 5222;
 public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
 public static final String USERNAME = "your gmail id";
 public static final String PASSWORD = "your gmail id password";

 private XMPPConnection connection;
 private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private EditText recipient;
private EditText textMessage;
private ListView listview;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.toET);
textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatET);
listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
setListAdapter();




// Set a listener to send a chat text message
Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    String to = recipient.getText().toString();
    String text = textMessage.getText().toString();          
    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", "Sending text " + text + " to " + to);
    Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);  
    msg.setBody(text);
    if ((connection != null)&& (!textMessage.getText().toString().equals("")))  {
      connection.sendPacket(msg);
      //messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
      messages.add("Rajesh :");

      messages.add(text);
      textMessage.setText("");
      setListAdapter();
    }
  else
  {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please type to compose ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
  }
});
 connect();
}

/**
 * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with 
* the XMPP server
 */
  public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
   this.connection = connection;
   if (connection != null) {
   // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
   PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
  connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
      Message message = (Message) packet;
      if (message.getBody() != null) {
        //String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
        String fromName="Gaurav";
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " +  fromName);
       messages.add(fromName + ":");
        messages.add(message.getBody());
        // Add the incoming message to the list view
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            setListAdapter();
          }
        });
      }
       }
    }, filter);
   }
 }

private void setListAdapter() {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, messages);
   listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 }



@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
try {
  connection.disconnect();

  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
}

public void connect() {

final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Create a connection
   ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
     XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
     try {
       connection.connect();
     Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+connection.getHost());
     } catch (XMPPException ex) {
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
         setConnection(null);
     }
      try {
        connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + connection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        setConnection(connection);

        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "--------------------------------------");
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "User: " + entry.getUser());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Name: " + entry.getName());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Type: " + entry.getType());
          Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getStatus());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

          Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
          if (type == Presence.Type.available)
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
          }
          } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "+  USERNAME);
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            setConnection(null);
          }
          dialog.dismiss();
       }
     });
   t.start();
   dialog.show();
 }

}
```

> **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minWidth="70dp"
  android:text="Chat With"
  android:textStyle="bold" />

 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/toET"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Add Recipient"
  android:minWidth="250dp"
  android:scrollHorizontally="true"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textSize="16sp" />
 </LinearLayout>

<ListView
 android:id="@+id/listMessages"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <EditText
   android:id="@+id/chatET"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="top"
   android:hint="Type to compose"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true" >
  </ EditText>

   <Button
  android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:text="Send"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> **listitem.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/text1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="false"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

> **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Its support bluetooth chat

```
 package com.example.bluetoothchat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
 private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices;
private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> aa;
private ListView list;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
private BluetoothSocket socket;
private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");

 @Override


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
foundDevices=new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();


bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();  


searchPairedDevice();


listenPairedDevice();

displayDeviceLists();

forExit();
  }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 private void displayDeviceLists() {
     aa = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foundDevices);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_discovered);    
    list.setAdapter(aa);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int index, long arg3) {
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> connectTask =  new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() { 
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
              try {
                BluetoothDevice device = foundDevices.get(params[0]);
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                socket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e)
                { Log.d("BLUETOOTH_CLIENT", e.getMessage());
              }
              return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              changeLayout();
            }
          };
        connectTask.execute(index);
      }      
    });

     }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 private void searchPairedDevice() {

     Button searchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_search);

     searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
         registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

         if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {

           foundDevices.clear();
           bluetooth.startDiscovery();
         }
       }
     });
      }
 BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device  the if statement added later by MR.
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        //added later by MR     
         bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();
     BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
      remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      if (bluetooth.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {  
      foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
      aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
      //added later by MR
      clearAbortBroadcast ();
      }
     }
     }
      };
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void listenPairedDevice() {
Button listenBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listen);
listenBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent disc = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(disc, DISCOVERY_REQUEST);     
 }
 });
}
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
boolean isDiscoverable = resultCode > 0;
 if (isDiscoverable) {
 String name = "bluetoothserver";
 try {
final BluetoothServerSocket btserver = bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);


      AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket> acceptThread = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket>() {

        @Override
        protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(Integer... params) {
          try {

             socket = btserver.accept();
            return socket;
             } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());            
          }
          finally {
            //close statement added later by MR
              try{
              btserver.close();
              } catch (IOException e){

              }
          }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket result) {
          if (result != null)
            changeLayout();
        }            
      };          
      acceptThread.execute(resultCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());            
    }
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 }


private void changeLayout() { 

final TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_messages);
final EditText textEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_message);
messageText.setEnabled(true);
messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
textEntry.setEnabled(true);

textEntry.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
  public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
      sendMessage(socket, textEntry.getText().toString());
      textEntry.setText("");
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }      
});
BluetoothSocketListener bsl = new BluetoothSocketListener(socket, handler, messageText);
Thread messageListener = new Thread(bsl);
messageListener.start();

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 private void sendMessage(BluetoothSocket socket, String msg) {
 OutputStream outStream;
  try {

  outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
  byte[] byteString = (msg + " ").getBytes();
  byteString[byteString.length - 1] = 0;
  outStream.write(byteString);
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
}    

 }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


private class MessagePoster implements Runnable {

private TextView textView;
private String message;

public MessagePoster(TextView textView, String message) {
  this.textView = textView;
  this.message = message;
}

public void run() {
  textView.setText(message);
}     

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private class BluetoothSocketListener implements Runnable {

  private BluetoothSocket socket;
  private TextView textView;
  private Handler handler;

  public BluetoothSocketListener(BluetoothSocket socket, 
                                 Handler handler, TextView textView) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.textView = textView;
    this.handler = handler;
  }

public void run() {
  int bufferSize = 1024;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];      
  try {
    InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
    int bytesRead = -1;
    String message = "";
    while (true) {
      message = "";
      bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
      if (bytesRead != -1) {
        while ((bytesRead==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)) {
          message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
        }
        message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1); 

        handler.post(new MessagePoster(textView, message));              
        socket.getInputStream();

      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
  } 
}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void forExit() {
Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {

    onDestroy();     
 }
 });
}




  public void onDestroy(){
      super.onDestroy();
      try{
          if (socket!=null) {
      socket.close();
          }
      } catch (IOException e){

      }
     finish(); 
  }
 }
```

main.xml

```
- <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <EditText android:id="@+id/text_message" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:enabled="false" /> 
  <Button android:id="@+id/button_search" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/text_message" android:text="SearchDevice" /> 
  <Button android:id="@+id/button_listen" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/button_search" android:text="ListenToDevice" /> 
  <ListView android:id="@+id/list_discovered" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@id/button_listen" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" /> 
  <TextView android:id="@+id/text_messages" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@id/button_listen" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:visibility="gone" /> 
  <Button android:id="@+id/stop" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:text="stop" /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.bluetoothchat" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> 
- <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
- <activity android:name="com.example.bluetoothchat.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```