# How to implement live chat in android without using any third party API?

Tags: android, sockets, chat

I want to implement chatting in my android app without using any third party API's like Jabber etc., How can I do it?

I want to implement it using Socket programming, but no exact Ideas to do it, Please help me!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try with XMPP Protocol.

Comment: Go through open source implementations to get an idea of how it is done. Check http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/ and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954712/android-whatsapp-chat-examples

Answer (score 2):

Just create a server in one device and a client in another device and connect the both using wifi hotspot in one of your android device.regarding the server and client code u will get many easily if u google it once. remember the client and server should be connected to a same network(wifi hotspot of any one of your android device).